# NFS - multi-drives

Tags: mount, nfs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 server and have NFS installed using 3 separate 1 TB drives I'd like to use as a file server. The problem I'm having is when I map the drives on my Windows 7 Enterprise machine, all drives will map/mount but then 1 of the 3 will fail to connect. If I map them x, y, z for instance x fails to connect in Windows Explorer. Strangely my backup software does connect and copy files to the share, but then I can't open the drive from Explorer and I get this "X:\ is not accessible the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect". What am I missing?

Comment: Do the volume labels or folders that you created have any special characters in them, or are they very long names? What are the names?